# Obtain the Phone Number through ADB

Tags: adb

I have a rooted Android device, and I'm set up with the Android Debug Bridge (ADB). I'm having difficulty finding the phone number of the device through ADB. I'm hoping to eventually automate this process if the phone connected to the computer is arbitrary.

I've tried google searching for the answer to this problem with no help, and I manually searched in some places on the phone.

How could I obtain the phone number through ADB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200788/how-to-get-the-phone-number-of-an-android-phone-via-adb

Comment: @AlexP. Wow, thanks Alex! I can't believe I didn't find that, I searched so deep for this question before I posted. Upvoted your answer, thanks!